# symfony2 overriding template and extending it

Tags: symfony, templates, overriding, twig

I have two bundle A and B, and B overrides A. One of templates B_tpl1 in B overrides the template A_tpl1 in A.

Till now this sounds easy, but now I want that my B_tpl1 extends A_tpl1. When I do that, I got an empty page on my browser and into my logs I got the message `memory exceeded...`.

I think what happens is that the extends statement tries to import A_tpl1, but it imports B_tpl1 instead since B override A, which makes it enter into an endless circular call.

The question in that case is: is it possible that B_tpl1 extends A_tpl1?

Comment: Could you post two example twig files showing your issue? I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

The embed tag combines the behaviour of include and extends. It allows you to include another template's contents, just like include does. But it also allows you to override any block defined inside the included template, like when extending a template.

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/embed.html

Comment: I've thought of it, but it didn't seem the right thing to do since what I need is really extending some template and not including it.